# UDP Socket Listener

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, bind, listen

when i try make UDP Socket Listener on server and Accept connection from client get this erroe when call `voiceSocket.Listen(5);` "The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced" this all code:

```
voiceSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        voiceSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, VPORT));
        voiceSocket.Listen(5);
        voiceSocket.BeginAccept(VoiceAceptCallback, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

UDP (`ProtocolType.Udp`) is connection-less protocol, you just send or receive data w/o any idea if there's somebody else on the other end of the line.

Probably you need TCP